# Manage a library of images: use blobs or links

Tags: database, image, sql-server-ce, blob, store

We have developed an **.Net/WPF application** that allows a user to create "**drawings**" from images provided through a DLL: it can save these drawings in a native format, or export as an image (PNG, JPEG , BMP, ...).

As part of an update of this application, we want to allow the user to manage these drawings in a internal database to offer new features:

- appearance of the notion of "**exercise**": an exercise = a drawing + a title + a description + properties
- possibility to use for exercise, a drawing created from the current version, or import an image (eg from the web)
- creation of sessions from several exercises

As the application is single-user, we want to use a light and free database, so we set off on the **SQL Server Compact** for its integration with our development environment.

However, we ask us questions relative to management of images:

- Is it better to store them directly in the database (as **BLOLBs**)?
- Is it better to save them physically on the computer, and store only **a link** in the database?

There is a limit of 4 GB for the size of a SQL Server Compact database, but it should allow sufficient flexibility to users.

- But in terms of performance, maintenance, and data's sharing, what is the best solution?
- Do you think that another database (SQLite) may be more appropriate?

Thank you in advance for your feedback,

Answer (score 0):

Your data is always at greater risk of becoming corrupt once you go the route of referencing external data rather than storing BLOBs.

As long as this risk is acceptable and you write code in your application to handle when data gets butchered (e.g., the user deletes referenced files from their file system), then you will have a great many scalable and performance gains by going with references.

If you cannot accept the risks, then use BLOBs.

Comment: In terms of data's "security", it would so be better to store the images in BLOBs.
But in terms of "performance", would there significant performance difference if the database is local?

Comment: Depends how you define "significant".